# issue with Intent while I want to take the map Uri and go to GoogleMap or browser to show the location

Tags: android, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the Longitude and Latitude and Intent user to the map but I get an error, I've searched in Stack and my method are exactly the same as other people, but I get crash when I call startActivity(intent) method.

here's my code:

```
public void routReq(View view) {

    if(saloon.getEntity_address() != null) {

        String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:  " + saloon.getEntity_address().getLatitude()+","+saloon.getEntity_address().getLongitude()+"&mode=d";

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(view, "there's no map for this place!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and this is the cause android studio gave me:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

which I did declare in Manifest.

```
<activity
        android:theme="@style/viewSaloneTheme"
        android:name="ir.drax.beautyTime.Activities.ViewSalon"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

and also:

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: same issue on Android Go Edition phone, Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `ActivityNotFoundException`, simply because the defined `activity` is not found in defined package by your intent. So,  instead of using `setClassName` as,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Use `setPackageName`. as,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

So, `GoogleMap` internally handle your intent(in it's defined activity). It will work.

Comment: still, crash on startActivity(intent); line

Comment: Still same exception ?

Comment: which one `activitynotfound` or `invocationtargetexception` ?

Comment: i get both of them

Comment: I've fixed it, I found the issue it was setPackage also another issue on parsing that String, I need to ask a question, what if I wanna check if the user has google map or not? if user doesn't have google map open it in the browser or so because I already tried it and if you don't have it it will crash, can I show user the option to and leave the choosing the app by User?

Comment: You can simply use `try-catch`. If app is not available it goes in catch, so simply start browser from catch.